# django2 + python3: TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I know there are multiple questions on this site about this problem, but I cannot find a solution.

I am using Python 3.6 (anaconda) + django 2.0.2 on Windows 10.

I am following the tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/

Here is my `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import *


def index(request):
    content = 'abcxyz'

    context = {'content': content}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

I created a file `index.html` in the folder `polls\templates\polls`

My `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_site.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_site.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

I have a problem of 'TemplateDoesNotExist' - it seems to me that django tries to look for a template in

```
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /mnt/e/workspace/capec-processing/code/django_site/polls/templates/polls/templates/polls/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/user_name/anaconda3/envs/capec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/polls/templates/polls/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/user_name/anaconda3/envs/capec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/polls/templates/polls/index.html (Source does not exist)
```

I am not sure what did I do wrong, because I followed the tutorial on the django website.

Could you suggest me a hint?

**Update**

Here is the structure of the my root directory (called `django_site`):

```
django_site
--django_site
----settings.py
--polls
----templates
------polls
--------index.html
----views.py
--db.sqlite3
--manage.py
```

Comment: Could you please post your project's directory structure? It might be possible that you have two different template directories and django is looking in the wrong one.

Answer (score 3):

In your setting.py you need to add this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls'   # You need to add this too. This should be same as your app name.
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],  # Add this to your settings file
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And your template folder should be here

```
myproject/
 |-- myproject/
 |    |-- polls/
 |    |-- myproject/
 |    |-- templates/     <-- here!
 |    |    |-- polls/
 |    |    |    |-- index.html
 |    |    |-- base.html
 |    |    +-- home.html
 |    +-- manage.py
 +-- venv/
```

Comment: You can skip the `INSTALLED_APPS` part, since there's nothing wrong with it. Plus, adding appConfig Class is the recommended way to add your local apps.

Comment: I am still using django 1.11.8. Thats why i didnt knew. i will do my research next time.

Comment: That recommendation [is there since Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#installed-apps) :)

Answer (score 1):

change value of `DIRS` under `TEMPLATES` to this to tell django to look for templates in your app directory.

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),],
```

and then you can either put templates parallel to **manage.py** or under specific app directory.

```
+app
-+__init__.py
-+templates
---+polls
-----+index.html
```

Comment: No, this is not needed and would not help OP. `'APP_DIRS': True` so he only need to put his template in the right directory.

Comment: it would be better if you have gone through the answer. I have specified this to include templates directory directly parallel to manage.py

Comment: I did go through the answer, but OP is specifically following the tutorial, so this is not what they want. He didn't ask how could he correct it, but what is he doing wrong. But yes, this may be a helpful answer after all.

Comment: By adding the content to ``'DIRS'`` variable, now it works. But yes, I have no idea why django cannot recognize the template file without explicitly state that.

Answer (score 1):

change your order of the installed apps in your settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add the name of your app, i.e. polls, to the list of installed apps in the settings.py file and reload the URL to the app index page. I don't know why the Django tutorial still does not include this step as it trips everyone up, every time.

**settings.py**

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   'polls',
]
```